# vertx module not found when using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

When using webpack and libraries that want to use when.js (`when`), it is possible that the following error is thrown when compiling:

```
[2] ERROR in ./node_modules/when/lib/env.js 32:14-35
[2] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vertx' in 'path-to-project/node_modules/when/lib'
```

The issue seems to be isolated to webpack, and is documented on `when`'s [github](https://github.com/cujojs/when/issues/482). Running `npm install vertx` or `npm install @vertx/core` will not resolve the issue either, since the problem lays in the import of vertx in the `when` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue:

Install `@vertx/core` (`npm i @vertx/core`)

Edit the file `./node_modules/when/lib/env.js`, and change line 32 from

```
var vertx = vertxRequire('vertx');
```

to

```
var vertx = vertxRequire('@vertx/core');
```

This will reference the @vertx/core package instead of the vertx package, which does not seem to be able to be found when using webpack and npm. I haven't experienced any issues with just using vertx/core. You might also need to update your gitignore to include the changes to the library if others are also working on your project.

Comment: I want to add that this should be done with a gulpfile and/or some automatic mechanism as node_modules gets overwritten every time a new install is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can indeed be solved by adding the `@vertex/core` package, but instead of editing the `./node_modules/when/lib/env.js` file manually as recommended by @Todd Rylaarsdam, I'd use the `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` in your Webpack config to replace the old `vertx` package, like so:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
  /^vertx/,
  '@vertx/core',
)
```

This way you don't have to make any manual changes to the files of a package you're using.

See https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/ for more info about this plugin.